# react native app crash on release mode on ios because of console.clear()

Tags: react-native

i Spend 5 hours trying to debug my react-native app who crash in release mode, crash log was not friendly at all

there was a `console.clear()` left in the code and this make the app crash totally in release mode, even with try-catch and error-boundary

i Hope this will help someone